# Why I get error when using TO_DATE() while converting from VARCHAR to Date data type

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently stuck in error which I don't understand clearly.

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

So far I check a couple of post here in  Stackoverflow but doesn't help me so much.
I have query something like

```
   SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT uta.StartDate,uta.EndDate
  FROM user_timesheets_absence uta
  LEFT JOIN users u 
  ON u.UserID = uta.UserID
  AND uta.Approved = '0'
  AND
  ((
    '2020-01-30' >= TO_DATE(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')
   AND
     '2020-02-06' <= TO_DATE(uta.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')
    )
    OR
    (
     '2020-01-30' <= TO_DATE(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')
 AND
     '2020-01-30' >= TO_DATE(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')
    ))
 --GROUP BY uta.UserAbsenceID
 UNION
 SELECT ut.DATE_ AS StartDate, 
        ut.DATE_ AS EndDate 
 FROM user_timesheets ut
 INNER JOIN moments m ON 
      m.UserTimesheetsID = ut.UserTimesheetsID
 WHERE
     TO_DATE(ut.DATE_,'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN '2020-01-21' AND '2020-01-30' + SYSTIMESTAMP + 1
  AND ut.user_id = 1
) a
```

Here is the problem which `StartDate` and `EndDate` filled are `VARCHAR2`
I try using 'TO_TIMESTAMP' and try to change format to `YYYY/MM/DD` but doesn't work.
I have to be honest that I don't have any idea so far what I made wrong here.
Where I made mistake ? What is wrong here ?

**UPDATE**

As GMB from answer said that using `validate_conversion()`  gives meall invalid date strings

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCGZ2.jpg)

And so far from query above, when I run it I get following error

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.
```

Comment: replace literals prefixed with `date` such as `date'2020-01-30'`, and  convert format model for `TO_DATE()` to `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: What is your Oracle version? 12.2 makes it easier to trace and handle issues like this.

Comment: The version is 12.2, latest one

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Yes I try this also and I get another error something like 
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: Another good example why it is an extremly bad idea to store date values in varchar columns. Do you have any chance to fix that broken data model?

Comment: Doest this tell you something ? https://i.imgur.com/2bcCqOY.jpeg

Comment: Check the answers to the other questions about this assignment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+user_timesheets_absence

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes, alredy check this but nothing is helped me. Thant why  I post question otherwise I wouldn't

Comment: Regarding the updated details, are you saying it is not possible to correct the data? The validate_conversion query told you which values are invalid. What do you want to do about them - fix them, ignore them, convert them using a different format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the strings in your column are invalid dates. Starting version 12.2, it is easy to exhibit them with function `validate_conversion()` clause of `to_date()`. The following query gives you all invalid date strings:

```
select date_
from user_timesheets 
where validate_conversion(date_ as date, 'YYYY/MM/DD') = 0
```

You can then fix your data.

You should consider using the `date` datatype to store dates, so that integrity is enforced at the time when the data is written.

In the meantime, let me suggest, however, to optimize the filtering logic: the formats of your strings make it possible to use direct filtering (without prior conversion to a date): this is more efficient, since it does not requires converting the entire column before filtering (on says that the predicate is SARGeable). Typically, you would replace something like:

```
to_date(uta.startdate,'yyyy/mm/dd') <= '2020-01-30'
```

With:

```
ut.startdate <= '2020/01/30'
```

Or if you are filtering agains the current system date:

```
ut.startdate <= to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I still have problem :(

Comment: @breezy if you could describe the problem in detail (including sample values, what you tried and the error message you got) I'm sure someone could help. When you tried the `validate_conversion()` test query, what happened? Is the problem that you now know which values are invalid (e.g. `'2020.'`) but you can't fix them?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Do I need to update my question or ... ?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I have been updated my question, you can check right now. 
What do you mean by (including sample values)  ??

Comment: @breezy I mean examples of the startdate and enddate values that aren't in valid YYYY/MM/DD format, as shown by `validate_conversion`. Please post them as text, not screenshots, because not everybody can view screenshots.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson As I show you in picture above I fix it by using UPDATE, but still have problem.

Comment: I don't see any `update` in your question, and the screenshot shows a column heading above a blank. Please post data as text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Not all `startdate` and `enddate` columns have values in `YYYY/MM/DD` format or - if they do - they are invalid.

For example: values like `2020/A8/43` or `ab3f/xy/2i` or `2020/15/02` and similar are **invalid**.

Error says that `MM` part of those strings isn't in range between `01` and `12`.

Comment: As I check now it tables all date format are in same format.

Comment: Format is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Does it mean that `select distinct to_date(startdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), to_date(enddate, 'yyyy/mm/dd') from user_timesheets_absence ` returns no error?

Comment: @breezy you can test that yourself. Try `select to_date('2020.','YYYY/MM/DD') from dual;` and see if it converts to a date.

Comment: As "it returns error", it means that your first comment ("all date format are in same format") isn't entirely true. There **are** errors there, and you'll have to fix them. Nothing new, but - this is what happens when people store dates as strings.

Comment: @Littlefoot I would like to change to store StartDate and EndDate as DATE but I ger error like I need to empty table and change it, but I can not do this since I have data inside tables

Comment: You'll have to create "temporary" columns of DATE datatype, put valid data in there, drop original VARCHAR2 columns, rename temporary columns to original names.

Comment: How to then insert a new data againg ? I have more then 10000  data in table ??

Answer (score 1):

First you should be storing date values using `date`, not strings.  One possibility is that these actually *are* dates and you don't need to reconvert them.  Without sample data, it is hard to say.  But you should put your effort into fixing the data.

Second, date constants in Oracle should look like:

```
DATE '2020-01-30'
```

So:

```
DATE '2020-01-30' >= TO_DATE(uta.StartDate,'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

Comment: I alredy check data type and it's ENDDATE VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)